# Only one system can be hooked up to MBP

Tags: drake

Why can I only hookup one system output port to plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port()?

Suppose I have two controllers controlling different objects.

I am forced to combine those two controllers into one controller to hook that controller up with the MBP spatial force input port.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you just need the [ExternallyAppliedSpatialForceMultiplexer](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_externally_applied_spatial_force_multiplexer.html).

If you can think of a good place in the documentation that would have helped you find this, do let us know.